# How to loop through dataframe and run regression in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, regression

I am trying to run a multiple regression on a dataframe in R, but am having lots of troubling thinking through how to approach iterating through each string in each column.

I have the following dataframe:

```
Category      Zone      Season       P1   P2    P3     Value     
-------------------------------------------------------------
   Blue         D1      Winter       1     4     4        55         
   Blue         D1      Winter       3     5     3        23         
   Blue         D1      Winter       5     3     1        25           
   ...          
   Blue         D1      Spring       3     3     2        32
   Blue         D1      Spring       2     2     3        23         
   Blue         D1      Spring       5     4     5        53 
   ...
```

I want to create a for lop that for each Category, for each Zone, for each Season, run a multiple regression of P1, P2, and P3 (P for "Parameter") as independent variables on Value. Note that there are of course many more rows in this analysis, where there will be many, many combinations of Parameter values for each combination of Category, Zone, and Season.

Can this easily be done in R? I feel like this would be a few lines of code using .lapply(), but I am still confused on how to actually organize this process.

I would appreciate any guidance on this problem! Thanks!

Comment: Here's an approach I like: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/vignettes/broom_and_dplyr.html

Answer (score 2):

Here's an application of the process described in the link I commented about above.

```
library(tidyverse); library(broom)
df1 %>% 
   nest(data = c(P1:Value)) %>%
   mutate(fit = map(data, ~lm(Value ~ ., data = .x)),
          tidied = map(fit, tidy)) %>%
   unnest(tidied)
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 8 x 10
  Category Zone  Season data             fit    term        estimate std.error statistic p.value
  <chr>    <chr> <chr>  <list>           <list> <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
1 Blue     D1    Winter <tibble [3 × 4]> <lm>   (Intercept)   111.         NaN       NaN     NaN
2 Blue     D1    Winter <tibble [3 × 4]> <lm>   P1            -10.3        NaN       NaN     NaN
3 Blue     D1    Winter <tibble [3 × 4]> <lm>   P2            -11.3        NaN       NaN     NaN
4 Blue     D1    Winter <tibble [3 × 4]> <lm>   P3             NA           NA        NA      NA
5 Blue     D1    Spring <tibble [3 × 4]> <lm>   (Intercept)     5.00       NaN       NaN     NaN
6 Blue     D1    Spring <tibble [3 × 4]> <lm>   P1             12.0        NaN       NaN     NaN
7 Blue     D1    Spring <tibble [3 × 4]> <lm>   P2             -3.00       NaN       NaN     NaN
8 Blue     D1    Spring <tibble [3 × 4]> <lm>   P3             NA           NA        NA      NA
```

Data

```
df1 <- data.frame(
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
              Category = c("Blue", "Blue", "Blue", "Blue", "Blue", "Blue"),
                  Zone = c("D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1"),
                Season = c("Winter","Winter","Winter",
                           "Spring","Spring","Spring"),
                    P1 = c(1L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 5L),
                    P2 = c(4L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L),
                    P3 = c(4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L),
                 Value = c(55L, 23L, 25L, 32L, 23L, 53L)
    )
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, I need to learn more about the tidyverse definitely. But what once I produce "df1" as you showed, how to I perform the regression and get a summary for each combination of Category, Zone, and Season?

Comment: df1 is just me expressing your provided data as code that can run on other computers. The "Result" section of my answer shows the regression summary produced by running the code at the top. For instance, the first four lines show the regression for Blue/D1/Winter, with estimated coefficients for the Intercept, P1, P2, and P3. Can you describe more what you're looking for if that's not it?